# Calling python function from javascript without jQuery

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I'm trying to make a web page that takes in user input and call a python function on it to get results asynchronously.What is the best way to call python functions from javascript?

I want to make it without using jQuery if possible.

Comment: are you using a webserver and using a python script as CGI script? You can send data in GET/POST and let the python script run in webserver.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API is the stadard tool for client-server communication